# Number of protocol messages (Page not found)

Tags: debugging

Why does i get a gigantic number of protocol messages for just one "page not found" request? How can i fix it? Isn't this a huge leak for the performance?

Comment: How did you test it? And why do you think it's Drupal's fault? Are you sure it is not simply a matter of "gigantic number" of requests that hit your server in the first place?

Comment: I tested it by simply calling a not existing URL.
But in protocol it shows up 21 warnings.

Comment: But you didn't do it from a client connected *directly* to your server, did you?

Comment: you mean on a local serverinstance. no.

Comment: I ask because i know no way Drupal would do it, but I've seen reverse proxies and fire walls to create similar effects. Unless you can be sure you bypassed all of them, I can't believe it's Drupal's fault.

Comment: It's never drupal's fault. But your hint could be a possible explanation for this behaviour. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Oh come on, often fault is in Drupal, either a bug or misconfiguration. I never denied that. Simply this time it looks for me like an outside issue.

Comment: As i looked a clone on a live system the behaviour is still the same without proxy / firewall. Still 21 warnings per browserrequest.